# JAXB unmarshalling list Java 6 not working, Java 7 works

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I'am trying to marshall and unmarshal a HashMap as a list. The marshalling works in both Java versions (6u45 and 7u21), but unmarshalling the list entries with Java 6u45 will deliver an empty myModels-HashMap. In Java 7u21, the myModels-HashMap is filled.

I have tried to use JAXB 2.2.7 with Java 6u45 (copied the jaxb-api.jar to the lib/endorsed dir) and the other jaxb-[core|impl|jxc|xjc] to my app lib and added them to the classpath), but i got the same result.

Thanks for your answers.

**The marshalled xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myStore>
    <myModels>
        <value>My Model 2</value>
        <myEnum>VALUE2</myEnum>
    </myModels>
    <myModels>
        <value>My Model 1</value>
        <myEnum>VALUE1</myEnum>
    </myModels>
    <name>My Store</name>
</myStore>
```

**MyModel:**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyModel {
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE1, VALUE2
}

private String value;
private MyEnum myEnum;

public MyModel() {

}

public MyModel(String value, MyEnum myEnum) {
    this.setValue(value);
    this.setMyEnum(myEnum);
}

public String toString() {
    return getValue() + ", " + getMyEnum();
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public MyEnum getMyEnum() {
    return myEnum;
}

public void setMyEnum(MyEnum myEnum) {
    this.myEnum = myEnum;
}
```

}

**MyStore:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
public class MyStore {
     private String name;
     private Map<String, MyModel> myModels = new HashMap<String, MyModel>();

     public MyStore() {

     }

     public MyStore(String name) {
         this.setName(name);
     }

     public void addMyModel(MyModel myModel) {
         myModels.put(myModel.getValue(), myModel);
     }

     public String getName() {
         return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }

     public List<MyModel> getMyModels() {
         return new ArrayList<MyModel>(myModels.values());
     }

     public void setMyModels(List<MyModel> myModels) {
         for (MyModel myModel: myModels) {
             this.myModels.put(myModel.getValue(), myModel);
         }
     }
}
```

**Test class for marshalling/unmarshalling**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import MyModel.MyEnum;

public class MyStoreTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        MyStore myStore = new MyStore("My Store");
        myStore.addMyModel(new MyModel("My Model 1", MyEnum.VALUE1));
        myStore.addMyModel(new MyModel("My Model 2", MyEnum.VALUE2));

        File fileMyStore = new File("MyStore.xml");

        JAXB.marshal(myStore, fileMyStore);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyStore.class,
                MyModel.class);
        Unmarshaller m = context.createUnmarshaller();
        MyStore myStoreFromXml = (MyStore) m.unmarshal(fileMyStore);
        System.out.println(myStoreFromXml.getName());
        for (MyModel myModel : myStoreFromXml.getMyModels()) {
            System.out.println(myModel.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _the unmarshalling doesn't work_ gives us almost no information. What happens?

Comment: @Keppil: Unmarshalling the list entries doesn't work. The hash-map is always empty.

Answer (score 2):

When unmarshalling a `List` property JAXB will check the the `get` method to see if a `List` has already been initialized.  If one is there it will be used to add the values to.  This allows you to choose what the underlying `List` implementation is.

Your `get` method always returns an instance of `ArrayList`.  Since it is not referenced by anything the data unmarshalled into it is lost.

If your `Map` is empty you could have your property return `null` instead of an empty `ArrayList` to get your use case to work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. If i return null the problem is, that in setMyModels the myModels is always empty (size 0). Should i use a custom Adapter to solve this issue?